# Anaconda on WSL2+ubuntu loads with windows home directory instead of ubuntu home

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have installed ubuntu linux distro on my windows 10 notebook pc by enabling WSL2.

Since I am working with pandas library and python, I have also installed anaconda on ubuntu. During installation, I allowed anaconda environment to load along with ubuntu whenever I load ubuntu on wsl2.

The setup seems to work fine. I am able to use VScode to edit my files and even run Jupyter notebook.

A strange issue I am noticing though at startup.

Every time ubuntu loads with anaconda, it always starts with my windows home folder instead of my home directory in the ubuntu distro.

```
(base) nisha@Lenovo-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Nishant$
```

and I always have to type the command `cd` to get to my ubuntu home directory to begin working on my projects.

```
(base) nisha@Lenovo-PC:~$
```

How do I change this behaviour and get to ubuntu and anaconda loading with my ubuntu home directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your startingDirectory in Windows Terminal settings

```
{
    "guid": "{c6eaf9f4-32a7-5fdc-b5cf-066e43243e40}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Ubuntu-18.04",
    "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
    "startingDirectory": "//wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04/home/wes/"
},
```

Comment: Note that your answer is for Windows Terminal specifically, but nowhere in the question did the OP mention that they were using Windows Terminal.

Comment: I give the solution because the ubuntu default terminal always opens at the home directory. Only the windows terminal opens at the windows home directory. That's why I thought he/she using Windows Terminal.

Comment: There are many methods of starting WSL that would result in a different directory.  The *default* is to use the current directory, and some applications start with the "current directory" being that of the user profile.  What's interesting in this user's case is that the way it sounds from the question, it only started happening after installing Anaconda and letting it modify the config files.  That leads me to believe it's more likely to be something in the bash startup configuration that Anaconda changed.

Comment: Thanks. You were right in guessing that I was using Windows Terminal. And this issue happened only after I installed anaconda on WSL2. I have since moved on to installing Ubuntu distro OS as a dual boot with windows and not using WSL anymore. Hence, unable to reproduce this issue now.